# Hash passwords in Node API or in Postgre Database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encryption, mobile, passwords

So I'm working on a mobile app that's driven by a node.js API. My question is, for hashing/storing passwords would it be better to hash them in the node API (with Bcrypt) then send this to the Postgres database, or should I send the plaintext password to the database and hash it using the `crypt()` function that is in `pgcrypto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send it to the database in plaintext, that is just one more spot where it can be accidentally logged or leaked, or spotted in transit.  Why do that if you don't need to?  If node.js has a trustworthy bcrypt API, then use it rather than using pgcrypto's.